# Morphia embedded list of linked objects search criteria

Tags: java, mongodb, search, morphia

I am using MongoDB and java-lib Morphia to deal with it.

I have a two classes:

```
class User {
   ...

   #Reference
   private List<Invoice> invoiceTransactions = new ArrayList<Invoice>();

   ...
}

class Invoice {
   ...

   User user;

   ...
}
```

When I create invoice I put it into the **invoiceTransactions** list

Now I have an **Invoice** object and my goal to find corresponding **User** if it does not contain this invoice inside the **invoiceTransactions** list.

That is what I wrote:

```
Invoice invoice = ...;

Query<User> query = (Query) dao.createQuery();
query.disableValidation().filter(Mapper.ID_KEY, u.getId());
List<Invoice> inv = new ArrayList<Invoice>();
inv.add(invoice);
query.criteria(User.INVOICE_TRANSACTIONS).hasNoneOf(inv);
```

That is the MongoDB log:

```
Wed Jul 18 19:03:09 [conn48] update dwh.UserImpl query: { _id: ObjectId('4ffbc8d
943b693ac766255f3'), InvoiceTransactions: { $nin: [ { className: "abc.InvoiceImpl", sum: 70.0, invoiceStatus: "NEW", creationDate:
new Date(1342627389037), _id: ObjectId('5006de3d022993ac397609c4'), guid: "4DEAB
CCE-63F9-1B0A-59F2-1135A83054B9", day: "2012.07.18", hour: "2012.07.18 19", minu
te: "2012.07.18 19:03" } ] } } update: { $set: { authId: "bla-bla" } } 0ms
```

You can see that **Invoice** object is processing not like *reference* but like *embedded* object. As a result I have that criteria firing even if the in fact **invoiceTransactions** contains Invoice.

So, my question is how to force morphia to look on the **inv** object as on reference not putting it into resulting query with all fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, here is the answer:

```
Key<Invoice> invoiceKey = dao.getDatastore().getKey(invoice);
List<Key<Invoice>> invoiceKeyList = new ArrayList<Key<Invoice>>();
invoiceKeyList.add(invoiceKey);
query.criteria(User.INVOICE_TRANSACTIONS).hasNoneOf(invoiceKeyList);
```